# Adobe FlashBuilder versus Telerik AppBuilder versus Intel SDK for mobile apps

Tags: cordova, flash-builder, appmobi, telerik-appbuilder

I have seen a number of questions here on SO about the differences between Xamarin and Titanium and PhoneGap, and they got tons of upvotes, so I believe this sort of comparison question to be on-topic. I am looking for facts, rather than opinions.

I'd like a comparison of Adobe FlashBuilder, Telerik AppBuilder, and Intel's mobile SDK (formerly appMobi), especially on the following points:

-- is a separate runtime needed on the mobile device or a single package?
-- is cross-compilation a possibility, to produce native binaries?
-- how are styles applied?
-- what about support for media queries?
-- relative performance
-- stability/robustness
-- debugging
-- IDE
-- any additional hardware required to produce iPhone apps?
-- market share/installed base

Comment: You should also check out Codename One which provides additional advantages over both and has a larger marketshare than Telerik as far as I can tell. It now also supports Cordova if necessary but has a superior framework of its own.

Answer (score 1):

Telerik AppBuilder and Intel XDK both leverage PhoneGap/Cordova for building hybrid mobile apps. Neither of them require a separate runtime on the device. Styles via CSS and media queries are fully supported.

With AppBuilder you also get to take advantage of [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/) (which allows you to develop truly native apps with JavaScript and CSS). Additionally with AppBuilder you get access to a great device simulator for all kinds of iOS/Android/WP devices + full featured debugging tools and a variety of IDE choices (web client, desktop client, Visual Studio extension, Sublime extension, and a CLI).

*Disclaimer - I am the Product Manager for AppBuilder here at Telerik.*